# Swagger Merge Multiple Specification

Tags: python, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have multiple swagger specifications generated by various independent modules;
Sample for 1 such specification :

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "tags": [
      {
        "name": "Tag1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tag2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Tag3"
      }
  ],
  "paths": {
      "/api/v1/entities/{entityId}/status": {
          "post": {
              "tags": [
              ],
              .
              .
              .
            }
          "get": {
              "tags": [
                "Tag1",
                "Tag3"
              ],
              .
              .
              .
            }
  },
  "/api/v1/entities": {
        "post": {
          "tags": [
            "Tag2",
            "Tag3"
          ]
          .
          .
          .
       }
   }
}
```

Each individual json file is complete with all it's reqd references. Is there any way using which I could combine them into a single specification (json file) ?

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine multiple motivations for doing this, for example providing a single swagger to import into AWS API Gateway. There may some off-the-shelf capabilities for merging JSON (e.g. https://pypi.org/project/jsonmerge/), however your best bet will be to implement this yourself. You may find the need to "namespace" the models within each swagger file to avoid conflicts. For example if file1.json and file2.json each have a "thing" model, these may not be consistent and in the merged swagger the definitions and usage should be merged as "file1_thing" and "file2_thing". Else you could also check for model consistency and avoid unnecessary namespacing.

Comment: any examples for 'off-the-shelf tools for merging JSON' ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a JSON-to-JSON transformation use case , so may be you can use Java based Jolt Transformation library . They have good examples here at the demo link as well : https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception . Here is the documentation link : https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt